# The right approach for building a text carousel with UIPageControl

Tags: ios, animation, swift, layout, carousel

I'm trying to reproduce a simple text carousel with UIPageControl, similar to the following login screen :

[image: spotify login screen]

---

```
I've created the following layout (view -> label , text):
```

[image: UI builder]
[image: view hierarchy]

---

**EDIT:** I've found some tutorials like :http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/ that uses the `UIPageViewController` however the result was "masking" my entire view disableing my exisiting interface.

**Issues that came up**:

1. I want to have multiple paragraphs similar to the created layout, should I build them without constraints? **- no just create one view as a "template"**
2. How can I break line in a text field, using the interface builder? **-solved : ALT + Enter**
3. What is the right way to animate the entering and leaving layouts?**-use the UIPageViewController, don't animate views**
4. Or maybe ... there is a library that will make my life much simpler **-could be, I've found the solution to be straight forward (at the end)**

**Q:** How would you implement such a feature? any good tutorial?

Comment: The answer to question 2 is to put '\n' (no quotes) in the text string. I think this only works when set it programmatically. E.G.: textField.text = "FirstLine\nSecondLine"

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Sure, I know how to do it at runtime. However it seems redundant if my text is fixed and hard coded. Looking for a way to do it with the interface builder

Comment: I hope you find out, I would like to know too :-)

Comment: Solved, check my edits :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After struggling with this feature, [**I'm sharing the project**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bww6GIoR7fFfSzlXdEE3UnBLdWc/view?usp=sharing), Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

I used the @Shlomi Schwartz's project and encountered a bug when I used more than 3 `UIPageViewController` (try with 4 `UIPageViewController` for example, using the @Shlomi Schwartz's project). The problem came from a missing and non implemented optional UIPageViewControllerDelegate's method, which drove the UIPageControl crazy.

Please find the particular method which fixes the bug below:

```
/*
    Optional UIPageViewControllerDelegate method

    Sent when a gesture-initiated transition ends. The 'finished' parameter indicates whether
    the animation finished, while the 'completed' parameter indicates whether the transition completed or bailed out (if the user let go early).
*/
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
    didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,
    previousViewControllers: [AnyObject],
    transitionCompleted completed: Bool)
{
    // Turn is either finished or aborted
    if (completed && finished) {
        let currentDisplayedViewController = self.pageViewController!.viewControllers[0] as! ContentViewController
        self.pageControl.currentPage = currentDisplayedViewController.index
    }
}
```

If you want to get the full working project, please find the Github link below:

([Github link of the project](https://github.com/King-Wizard/Swift-Spotify-Like-Carousel))

Note: thank you again to @Shlomi Schwartz for having shared with the community the initial snippet (very useful). I also did not forget to mention him as a main author in the source code.